# how to install apk with odex file

Tags: android

all

I want to made some modification of Settings, then I build it, the outputs generated two files

```
Install: out/target/product/g32ref/system/app/Settings.odex
Install: out/target/product/g32ref/system/app/Settings.apk
```

Then I install the apk using

```
adb install  -r out/target/product/g32ref/system/app/Settings.apk
```

error is

```
adan@adan-Latitude-D630:~/myproject$ adb install  -r out/target/product/g32ref/system/app/Settings.apk
228 KB/s (7510110 bytes in 32.109s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Settings.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

how to push or install the generated files to the device? thank you very much!!

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you've got 2 options :

1. It seems you've access to the sources of the system Settings app, so you can disable in a sense the generation of the escorted **odex** file and have self-contained APK (which includes **classes.dex** within it) via plugging in your Android.mk the following flag `LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false`
2. Stick w/ the escorted odex file (for sake of performance etc. etc.) but instead of using **adb install** simply use **adb push** of your apk file and .odex.gz to /system/app/ (**adb remount** probably will be needed as a setup phase)